# Segmentation fault in boost file system path

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault

I have a member function within a verify class that generates a hash for a set of files.

The code compiles correctly though when the software reaches the hashing function it throws a seg fault. I have been looking for ages and I just can't see it. It seems to be something to do with the path vector and maybe the copy function.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055c84fbbc058 in std::vector<boost::filesystem::path, std::allocator<boost::filesystem::path> >::push_back(boost::filesystem::path const&) ()
(gdb) 
Single stepping until exit from function _ZNSt6vectorIN5boost10filesystem4pathESaIS2_EE9push_backERKS2_,
which has no line number information.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

output from gdb

code below:

```
#pragma once
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

#include <cryptopp/cryptlib.h>

#define CRYPTOPP_ENABLE_NAMESPACE_WEAK 1
#include <cryptopp/md5.h>
#include "cryptopp/hex.h"
#include "cryptopp/files.h"

class Verify {
    private:
    typedef std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> vec;
    vec v;
    public:
    bool verify_files();
    bool generate_hash(boost::filesystem::path source);
};
```

function implementation

```
bool Verify::generate_hash(boost::filesystem::path source) {
    try {
    if (boost::filesystem::exists(source)) {                                                   //make sure path is valid
      if (boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(source)) {                                        //no regular files
        std::cout << "Please enter base path of directory only." << std::endl;
        return false;
      }
      else if (boost::filesystem::is_directory(source)){                                       //process directory here
        std::cout << "Scanning " << source << std::endl;

        std::copy(boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(source), boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(), std::back_inserter(this->v));
        std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

         for (vec::const_iterator it (v.begin()); it != v.end(); ++it){
           std::string result;
           if (boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(*it)) {
               Weak::MD5 hash;
               FileSource((*it).string().c_str(), true, new HashFilter(hash, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(result), false)));
            }
            std::cout << "Hashing: " << *it << " - " << result << std::endl; 
        }
      } 
    }
    } catch (const boost::filesystem::filesystem_error& e){
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is on this line:

```
std::copy(boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(source), boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(), std::back_inserter(this->v));
```

You should do a manual loop here instead to investigate further (if that doesn't eliminiate the issue)

Comment: for(auto& p: boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(source)){
            std::cout << p.path() << std::endl;
            this->v.push_back(p.path());
        } Tried this but still getting a seg fault on the push back function